# Is a stereotype name case sensitive?

Tags: uml, naming-conventions, stereotype

I remember a conversation with a Sparx employee telling me that stereotype names are not case sensitive. (Probably/of course because EA ignores the casing.) Roughly searchiung the UML 2.5 specs did not give me any result for the keywords I used. So: does anyone have a reference where the UML specs tells us about casing of stereotypes (and keywords)?

Comment: Seems my memory does not serve so well any more ....